# RMarkdown numbering multiple figures/tables in one chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

My RMarkdown document has code chunks that generate multiple figures or tables from within one chunk.  For instance, it loops through a bunch of variables to generate summary statistics tables for each variable. The problem is that the numbering of these figures/tables is often wrong when I try to generate a HTML document; this problem doesn't happen when I compile a PDF. The problem is that all the tables generated from the same chunk would get the same table number.

Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Testing Section Numbers"
author: "Authors"
date: "January 2019"
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    number_sections: yes
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

# R Markdown

Text text text 

```{r pressure1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap=c("This is my plot", "This is my other plot")}
plot(pressure)

plot(iris)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
kable(pressure, caption = "My first table")
kable(pressure, caption = "My second table")
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug of **knitr**, which [I just fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/caf83fb6914ed41ead16f6e41be534a6868d3eff) in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) on Github. Please try

```
remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! The figure numbers are fixed but the problem exists for tables made using the `kable` function. I have updated the original post to include an example with two tables in one chunk. If there is a solution to the table numbering problem, that would be great.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to generate one table per code chunk... This issue sounds a trickier to solve to me.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @yaleeconjournal If you install **knitr** from Github again, you can manually assign labels to tables, e.g., `knitr::kable(iris, label = 'iris'); knitr::kable(mtcars, label = 'mtcars')`. Then use `\@ref(tab:iris)` and `\@ref(tab:mtcars)` for cross-references.